# Flutter ios run crash because of admob

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins, admob

When i try to open my flutter app in ios getting multiple errors below. All of my ad Id's and aplication id is true, also edited info.plist with my app id. How can i solve this issue

**Errors**

```
In file included from /Users/user190797/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.11.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTRewardedVideoAdWrapper.m:6:
    /Users/user190797/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.11.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin.h:28:4: error: expected a type
    - (GADUnifiedNativeAdView *)createNativeAd:(GADUnifiedNativeAd *)nativeAd
       ^
    /Users/user190797/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.11.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin.h:28:45: error: expected a type
    - (GADUnifiedNativeAdView *)createNativeAd:(GADUnifiedNativeAd *)nativeAd
                                                ^
```